# Can Apps Scripts Google Drive API talk with Shared Drives

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

All,
I am having trouble using the Google Drive API in my Apps Script, in conjunction with a Shared Drive. When I run the code below, I receive the error "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: File not found."

The same code works with a file on My Drive, so it is an issue with Shared Drives. The code is running as myself, and I am the owner of the Shared Drive. Any ideas?

```
function insertPermission() {

  var resource = {
    // enter email address here
    value: 'xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com', 
    
    // choose from "user" or "group" if using a Google Group
    type: 'user',                
    
    // choose from: "owner", "writer" or "reader"
    role: 'writer'               
  };
  
  var optionalArgs = {
    sendNotificationEmails: false
  };
  Drive.
  Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, 'TokenIDGoesHere', optionalArgs);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the [request parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert?) `supportsAllDrives` to `true` in order to be able to make such a request to a shared drive.